# Showing PDF files with AxAcroPDFLib

Tags: c#, acrobat-sdk

Using the AxAcroPDF object in C#, is there anyway to hide the hover bar that pops up ? My motivation using this control is to be able to show PDFs to my users, but disallow them from saving copies of the PDFs. Alternatively, does anybody know of any controls other than Adobe's that can be embedded in a WPF application using C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this writing, the Adobe COM component does not support hiding the floating hover bar, so the users can save the PDFs. I wound up using the PDFView4NET library from O2 solutions which gave me the customizability that I needed.